# SQl Server : sort alphanumeric first followed by Numeric

Tags: sql, sorting, alphanumeric

```
SELECT  dbo.base_project.id as ID, 
        dbo.base_project.name as Name,
        dbo.base_project.status
FROM         dbo.base_project
ORDER BY   
Case When IsNumeric(dbo.base_project.name) = 1 
     then Right(Replicate('0',21) + dbo.base_project.name, 20)
     When IsNumeric(dbo.base_project.name) = 0 
     then Left(dbo.base_project.name + Replicate('',21), 20)
     Else dbo.base_project.name End
```

I'm able to sort numerically then alphanumeric.I need to reverse sort, where i need to sort Alphanumeric first and then Numerical

**Example:**

`1,
3,
13036,
101-2011-009X2,
20-100281-01,
ELO-001,
ELO001B,
ELO002B`

Comment: Do you mean on the same field?  Is the example data the data you have in the column being sorted?  You should update the question with the query and schema you are working on and the result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Provide some more info like query and schema

Comment: @Madrid. So you are currently getting the names in this order: 1, 3, 13036, 101-2011-009X2, 20-100281-01, ELO-001, ELO001B, ELO002B but you want them in this order:  ELO-001, ELO001B, ELO002B, 1, 3, 13036, 101-2011-009X2, 20-100281-01?

Comment: I missed typed, is this the desired order: 101-2011-009X2, 20-100281-01, ELO-001, ELO001B, ELO002B, 1, 3, 13036?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a subquery.  The subquery separates the numeric from the not numeric and gives them calculated fields so they can be used in the order by of the main query.

```
SELECT 
    A.ID
,   A.Name
,   A.status
FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        dbo.base_project.id as ID
    ,   dbo.base_project.name as Name
    ,   dbo.base_project.status
    ,   1 as ordering
    ,   RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',21) + dbo.base_project.name, 20) As padded
    FROM dbo.base_project
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(dbo.base_project.name) = 1
UNION
    SELECT  
        dbo.base_project.id as ID
    ,   dbo.base_project.name as Name
    ,   dbo.base_project.status
    ,   0 as ordering
    ,   LEFT(dbo.base_project.name + REPLICATE('',21), 20) As padded
    FROM dbo.base_project
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(dbo.base_project.name) <> 1
) A
ORDER BY A.ordering, A.padded
```